# android vpn connection

Tags: android, vpn

I am trying to launch a vpn connection programmatically. I am getting this error. I am using  Android 2.1 and my test phone kernel version is 2.6.32.9.
I am able to connect to vpn when i do it manually. But programmatically, I am getting this error.

```
java.io.IOException: cannot start service: mtpd
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.DaemonProxy.start(DaemonProxy.java:75)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.VpnDaemons.startDaemon(VpnDaemons.java:106)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.VpnDaemons.startMtpd(VpnDaemons.java:127)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.VpnDaemons.startL2tp(VpnDaemons.java:50)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.L2tpService.connect(L2tpService.java:31)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.VpnService.onConnect(VpnService.java:135)
E/VpnService(11817):    at com.android.vpn.VpnServiceBinder$2.run(VpnServiceBinder.java:130)
E/VpnService(11817):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

DeamonProxy: 75 points to the following method.

```
private boolean blockUntil(String expectedState, int waitTime) {
        String cmd = SVC_STATE_CMD_PREFIX + mName;
        int sleepTime = 200; // ms
        int n = waitTime * 1000 / sleepTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (expectedState.equals(SystemProperties.get(cmd))) {
                if (DBG) {
                    Log.d(mTag, mName + " is " + expectedState + " after "
                            + (i * sleepTime) + " msec");
                }
                break;
            }
            sleep(sleepTime);
        }
        return expectedState.equals(SystemProperties.get(cmd));
    }
```

This method times out and return the above error.

Any help/suggestion on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this class

The VpnService.java Android example source code

http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/packages/VpnServices/src/com/android/server/vpn/VpnService.java.shtml

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).